# Verify if a string has determined word according an array of set of words and then change this target word found

Tags: ruby

Here some contextualization. It's not what I'm trying to do, but the mechanics is similar. I think I will grasp what I want with this problem.

I have an array with a set of bad words lets say. I want to build a method which receive an string (someone messege) that will filter the bad words according to the set of words previouslsy setted. And then replace the bad words found with "[removed]".

Comment: What's the specific issue? Seems like a simple global replace and a regex created from that list of words (or simple iteration).

Comment: @Dave's first suggestion can be implemented as follows. Suppose `bad_words =  ['bad', 'badmouth', 'badlands', 'badmitten']`. First construct a regular expression to identify words to be matched: `r = /\b#{Regexp.union(bad_words)}\b/
 #=> /\b(?-mix:bad|badmouth|badlands|badmitten)\b/`. Then use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) to make the replacements: `"Simbad thought the badlands were really bad".gsub(r, "[removed]") #=> "Simbad thought the [removed] were really [removed]"`. The word-breaks, `\b`, prevent words such as "Simbad" from being matched...

Comment: ...See [Regexp::union](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Regexp.html#method-c-union).

Comment: thanks guys. I have encoutered many regular expression in many question, but never could understand completly the meaning of all characters. It would be quite powerful to know this!